# How do I present data as part url param, part json object?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api, jsonp

We have an API method called Create that receives the below data in JSON format

```
 {data: 
      {
        "token":"73264280-be3f-4f5b",
        "BuildingDisplay":"Fire Station 21 Fairburn - 19 East Broad St.",
        "CallerEmail":"Jim.Parker@yahoo.com",
        "CallerFax":"",
        "CallerFirstName":"Jim",
        "CallerLastName":"Parker",
        "CallerMiddleInitial":"",
        "CallerOtherPhone":"",
        "CallerState":"",
        "CallerWorkPhone":"918-354-2874"}}
```

Can someone please show how to get the API to receive data in the following format:

```
http://folder/users/Create?data={"BuildingDisplay":"Fire Station 21 Fairburn - 19 East Broad St.",
        "CallerEmail":"Jim.Parker@yahoo.com",
        "CallerFax":"",
        "CallerFirstName":"Jim",
        "CallerLastName":"Parker",
        "CallerMiddleInitial":"",
        "CallerOtherPhone":"",
        "CallerState":"",
        "CallerWorkPhone":"918-354-2874"}&token=73264280-be3f-4f5b
```

Many thanks in advance.

```
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "proxyCheck.php",
 data: '{data: ' + JSON.stringify(myData) + '}',
 contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 async: false,
 success: function (response) {
 alert("Record has been added successfully.");
 window.location.reload();
 }
 });
  return false;
 }
```

//Then proxyCheck.php:

```
  <?php

 //DESCRIPTION: Allow Ajax scripts to request content from a web service they otherwise may not be able to. 

 $ch = curl_init("http://Users/Services/Create");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $output
  ?>
```

Comment: Why not getting JSON data parameter in HTTP POST body? Why do you need HTTP GET for this?

Comment: @AlexP, I thought I was using POST method?

Comment: So your question is how to submit this data with `jquery` with cross domain request? When you wrote this JSON data in URL, then you are actually trying to submit it via GET. With `jsonp` you can use GET without too much headache. For POST you will need to make the server to support CORS.

Comment: @ALexP, I am sorry I was so concerned about being too wordy and losing my audience that I didn't provide all the information needed.

We have a file called proxyCheck.php.
This file helps use get around get around cross domain issue.

So, the ajax posts the json data to proxyCheck.php which in turn posts the data to the `Create` API method.

I have updated my code above to see how we are doing it.

Comment: No worries about being too wordy as long as it is structured and contains relevant code and tags. For example, `jsonp` is irrelevant for this question. I think you need to focus on your PHP code, when you get parameters from POST (which you get from Ajax) and translate it to subsequent GET request. By the way, can't `Create` service extract all these parameters from POST body?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "proxyCheck.php",
  data: {data: JSON.stringify(myData)},
  contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  success: function (response) {
    alert("Record has been added successfully.");
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

Edit:
To clarify, if you want the parameters in the URL you need to use `type: "GET"`.
For the JSON, you stringify the value, but you want the ajax `data` parameter to be an object, as usual. jQuery will loop over all keys in the `data` and append them to the query string.

Note that there are some upper limits to the amount of data you can pack into a query string, though I think you are well within those for modern browsers.

2nd Edit: Proxy uses POST, so it must be POST.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work. This is what your solution shows:

`proxyCheck.php?{data:%20{%22Token%22:%226f44bba1-69ab-4c92-93e5-537fff732548%22,%.

First, this is not JSON formatted. Second, it needs pass these values to the Create method so the Create method receives the data in the following format:
`Create?data={"name": "john doe", etc}&token=aaaaaaa`

Comment: Apologies, I believe I misread the layers of redirection. You show a URL with a query string (GET) but you seem to refer to POST both times. Is your proxy expecting POST?

Comment: I have tested the `data: { data: JSON.stringify(myData) }` and that is formatting the data as I expected. Based on the $_POST, it appears you do need POST at least to the proxy, but the API example you give would suggest the API uses GET.

Comment: If the API needs get, you won't use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, you'll need to concatenate the data onto the URL, something like this: `curl_init("http://Users/Services/Create?" . $_POST);

Comment: when I tested yours using ff, the proxyCheck.php file displays the data as I posted earlier with a bunch of %22, etc.

As a result, the API returns the following error:

`  {"Value":null,"Status":2,"Message":"No auth token supplied."}`

So, it is not seeing the token.

Comment: That's URL encoding. In PHP you can use `urldecode(string)` to fix that.